# How to resize view when using UINavigationController setToolbarHidden:animated:

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using the `UINavigationController` toolbar. Before I display it, I resize my views so that they don't get blocked by the toolbar (I set the frame of the current view controller's view to the rect spanning from the bottom of the `navigationBar` to the top of the `toolbar`.

But not all of my view controllers have `toolbarItems`. So, when switching from a view controller that has items (controller A) to one that doesn't (controller B), I want to hide the toolbar. However, when I call `setToolbarHidden:animated:` in B's `viewWillAppear:animated:` method, the toolbar animates down during the push transition and shows the `UIWindow` background behind it.

This also happens in the reverse direction: when transitioning from B to A (via the back button), I want the toolbar to animate in to show A's `toolbarItems` again, but since A's view doesn't extend to the bottom of the screen, the `UIWindow` is visible during the pop transition.

That might not have been the best description, so here's a screenshot:

[image: Cmd-shift-3 rapid-fire FTW]

I have tried updating A's frame in its `viewWillDisappear:animated:` method, but it does strange things, since it seems to be called within the `UINavigationController` push animation block. Any insight would be appreciated.

**Update**: I tried hiding the toolbar in B's `viewDidAppear:animated:` instead, but the results weren't ideal. Using this solution, the toolbar doesn't get dismissed until the push transition completes. Since B doesn't have any `toolbarItems`, A's items get pushed to the left during the transition, leaving an empty toolbar on the screen before it disappears. Also, when going back to A, the `UIWindow` background will be visible unless I set the toolbar to visible in B's `viewWillDisappear:animated:`, which would mean that B has to know that A has `toolbarItems`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I never found a satisfactory solution to this involving animation, I ended up making my views extend down behind the toolbar to avoid showing the window. If your controller's view is a UITableView or UIScrollView, you can set its `contentInset` appropriately so that your content won't get covered up by the toolbar:

```
UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = [[self tableView] contentInset];
if (![[self navigationController] isToolbarHidden]) {
    edgeInsets.bottom = CGRectGetHeight([[[self navigationController] toolbar] frame]);
}
[[self tableView] setContentInset:edgeInsets];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best practice would be to call `setToolbarHidden:animated:` in B's `viewDidAppear`?

Or you can change A's frame before pushing B to navigation controller in a `pushViewController:animated:` method in a custom `UINavigationController` subclass.

Comment: I just tried moving `setToolbarHidden:animated:` into B's `viewDidAppear:animated:`. It successfully covers up the `UIWindow` background during the forward transition, but I don't like how it waits for the push to finish before dismissing the toolbar. Since B has no `toolbarItems`, A's items transition left, leaving the toolbar empty before it gets dismissed.

Comment: As for the `UINavigationController` subclass suggestion, that's something [Apple doesn't want people doing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: The Apple docs now say, "This class is generally used as-is but may be subclassed in iOS 6 and later."